# How to enable Spark web interface on Dataproc(GCP) using DataprocCreateClusterOperator of Apache Airflow

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-dataproc, dataproc

We are using Apache Airflow's `DataprocCreateClusterOperator` to create Spark cluster on GCP(Dataproc) and wanted to enable Spark Web UI interfaces. When creating using terminal we pass `--enable-component-gateway` in the create cluster command. How can we achieve this using `DataprocCreateClusterOperator`

We tried adding below`endpoint_config`(sample code below), but no luck.

```
"software_config" : {
.....,

   "endpoint_config" : {
   "enable_http_port_access" : "true"
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Dataproc REST API ([Cluster](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.regions.clusters#Cluster), [ClusterConfig](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/reference/rest/v1/ClusterConfig), [EndpointConfig](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/reference/rest/v1/ClusterConfig#EndpointConfig)), it should be

```
{
  "clusterName": ...,
  ...
  "config": {
    "endpointConfig": {
      "enableHttpPortAccess" : true
    },
    "softwareConfig": {
      ...
    },
    ...
  }
}
```